# How to remove points from Path CustomView

Tags: java, android, view, android-custom-view

I created a custom view to plot points on user touch.

> onDraw()

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mCanvas = canvas;
    if (null != mPath && null != mPaint)
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

> onTouchEvent()

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (null == mPath) {
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
        if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
            mOnDrawListener.onStartDraw(this);
        }
        mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == event.getAction()) {
       /* if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
            mOnDrawListener.onDrawing(this, getBitmap());
        }*/
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
        if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
            mOnDrawListener.onStopDrawing(this, getBitmap());
        }
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

And the problem was I have two `MODES`  *PEN and ERASER*. If `Mode.PEN` was selected I have to draw the view. That was a success.

But when the user selects `Mode.ERASER` I want to remove the line or particular points from `path`.

**EDIT**

I can't use point because point in list have to plot using `for` loop of `while` loop and it will slow down the drawing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the whole canvas

```
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

You can also see the same functionality on this library

[Signature Pad](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)

Comment: Can the library above fulfill your needs?

Comment: @Godwin so did the library helped or didnt cut it?

Comment: It uses another technique. rather than creating path it creates a bitmap. In my problem that is not gave me any solution.

Comment: And I applied that bitmap creation technique , but It slow down by process. ui hangs every time if I create bitmap

Comment: The library does create a path. Infact it creates the path(s) where the user is interacting. Also you should create the bitmap on a worker thread not on the ui thread. Please try and let me know

Comment: Ok I will try it and inform you

Comment: Try it and hope it will help. Just try to do image processing related work on the worker thread else ui will not be able to handle it.